# Replace all slash by backslash within specified tag for file path

Tags: python, regex, replace, backslash, slash

I have xml like file with tags like:

```
<id>SomeID</id>
<datasource>C:/projects/my_project/my_file.jpg</datasource>
<title>My title can include / and other characters</title>
<abstract></abstract>
```

**I want to change all slashes to backslashes but only within tag** datasource (within opening and closing tag).

What is the general regex syntax to do that? **UPDATE:** I finally got to the first working solution with python:

```
regex_01 = re.compile(".*<datasource>")
regex_02 = re.compile("</datasource>.*")
file_content = ""        
for line in source_file.readlines():
    if "<datasource>" in line:
        start = regex_01.search(line).group()
        end = regex_02.search(line).group()
        part_to_replace = line.replace(start,"").replace(end,"")
        replaced = part_to_replace.replace("/","\\")
        file_content = file_content + start + replaced.strip() + end + "\n"
    else:
        file_content = file_content + line
```

Could you suggest something more elegant?

Comment: Can you use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` - what language is it? (only for Perl, PCRE and Python)

Comment: @antoni I started to test in notepad++ but I guess it won't be possible to do it there so I am keen for solution in **python**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this with the skip/fail syntax:

```
(?:<datasource>[^/]*?|.*(?=<datasource>)|(?=</datasource>).*)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|/
```

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/86gc4d/1.

But this one is for PCRE. In python, `(*FAIL)` can also be `(?!)` but for `(*SKIP)` I am not sure.

If I am not wrong it should be added in latest python regex engine: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex.

You can find the documentation of `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` syntax here: http://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html#skipfail, where it also says it works in Python in the example of that paragraph:

```
# Python
# if you don't have the regex package, pip install regex

import regex as mrab

# print(regex.__version__) should output 2.4.76 or higher
print(mrab.findall(r'{[^}]*}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b\w+\b',
                   'good words {and bad} {ones}'))
# ['good', 'words']
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, at the end I have created cumbersome but working code. Not sure I have regex available, will test it later and accept this answer if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?=ce>)[\s\S]*?(?<=<\/d)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/VVcUMy/2

Comment: This is not what Miro tries to do. He tries to replace slashes with backslashes only inside datasource tag.